# Can't get "crossroads" to load as requirejs AMD module in typescript

Tags: requirejs, typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to port a javascript app to typescript that uses requirejs. I am using the typedefinition from @mhegazy at DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/crossroads
Typescript compiler is giving me the following error...

error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'crossroads'.

This did all work in javascript using "defines" instead.

I just used this library as a complete example.  What am I missing?  Documentation is hard to dig up if TSC is really even paying attention to a requirejs config. I know crossroads depends on js-signals. 
Is there a problem with definitions and ts files being in different directories?
From what I have read [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript) I should not have to even put the reference comment. But if I then try to use a relative path, it cannot find it either.

Here is my app structure

- index.html

**Application ts/js**

- app/config.ts
- app/bootup.ts
- app/someclass.ts

**Typescript definitions**

- typings/crossroads/crossroads.d.ts
- typings/requirejs/require.d.ts

**Javascript libraries**

- bower_components/crossroads/dist/crossroads.js
- bower_components/requirejs/require.js

**index.html has this script include**

```
<script data-main="app/config" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js>
</script>
```

**/app/config.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
(function () {
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: ".", 
        paths: { 
            "crossroads": "bower_components/crossroads/dist/crossroads"
        }
    })
    require(["app/bootup"]);
}) ();
```

**/app/someclass.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/crossroads/crossroads.d.ts" />
import crossroads = require("crossroads");

class SomeClass{
 // do something with crossroads
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import crossroads = require("crossroads");`

To use `import/require` you either need:

- relative path pointing to a *TypeScript* file.
- a declared external module.

In your case *you need to declare an external module* for TypeScript to know about it. E.g.:

```
declare module 'crossroads'{
    export = crossroads;
}
```

**UPDATE** I've updated the definitions so you don't need to do this : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/3866 Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome - I came to the same conclusion and was going to do a pull request.  why does the declare module name need to be a string?  is typescript actually reading the requirejs config? thanks!

Comment: Also - crossroads depends on js-signals.  What is the proper way to include this dependency in a a class that uses crossroads? Does the require js config shim take care of it? Or should there be an actual import in the typescript class, in which case it would need the module declaration as well...I have seem amd-dependency notation as well.

Comment: is typescript actually reading the requirejs config? No. It means that there is something defined elsewhere that can be require/imported

Comment: Why do virtually no typedefinitions on definitely typed declare external modules for this purpose?

Comment: Because these libs were not on NPM || people who wrote the defs didn't use external modules